# Error on stared Appium when stared webdriver

Tags: automation, webdriver-io, appium-android

When i stared:

```
npx wdio
```

```
appium -p 4728
```

with config

```
exports.config = {
    runner: 'local',
capabilities: [{
        "platformName": 'Android',
        "appium:deviceName": 'teste2',
        "appium:platformVersion": "13.0",
        "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
        "appium:app": androidAppPath,
        "appium:appWaitActivity": "br.com.dasa.am.coletador.MainActivity"
    }],
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    services: ["appium"],
   ,
```

Recive this erro:
Error: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1)
Solution on this error